Is it possible to link fhir models into auto query?
Is it possible to link fhir models into auto query?
Using the UI components and others to facilitate writing a blazor app
Want to use fhir and auto query to build a blazor app
Want to commit into a solution for the project

AutoQuery provides a an Auto API and UI solution for supported RDBMS's.
No idea how "fhir models" are physically stored, but if it's maintained in RDBMS tables you can try creating a typed OrmLite data model that matches the RDBMS table:
class MyTable
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  //.. properties
}

Which will then let you create AutoQuery APIs for it, e.g:
public class QueryMyTable : QueryDb<MyTable> {}

If you have an existing RDBMS, AutoQuery AutoGen can get you started quickly by generating RDBMS Tables and AutoQuery APIs for existing tables.
If "fhir models" doesn't use an RDBMS then you're limited to using AutoQuery Memory or AutoQuery Service Data Source to populate an In Memory collection you can query.
